# How to show a html form once a day or have refresh to show it again

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello guys,

I'm trying to make a website where everybody can post on front page everything they want, but for security reasons I don't like spamming. What i want is when someone posts something, then they can do it only once a day!! (sorry if my English is not understandable)
 [image]
this is my form

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<br><div id="myButton"><input id="myInputButton" type="submit" value="Δημοσίευση">             </div>
<input type="text"  maxlength="70" size="80" name="text">
</form>`
```

the posting code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT text, id, link,votes_up,votes_down FROM   post ORDER BY id DESC"); 
       mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");  
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $text =  $row['text'];
     $net_vote = $row['votes_up'] - $row['votes_down'];
     echo '<div id="posts">'.'<h2>Καποιος ειπε:</h2>'.'<p><b><font size="3px">' . $text .     '</font></b></p><hr>'
;`
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to check via IP, but this is easily bypassable.

Comment: use `cookie` or `session` for validation.

Comment: Or a combination of IP, cookies, session and HTML5 local storage.

Comment: i know you guys, but i need somebody to submit the code here -.-

Answer (score 1):

If people can post to the front page of your website then you want some form of user registration. When a user registers you’ll be able to identify them by ID, so therefore can store a `last_posted` timestamp in the database. When they post, check the timestamp is older than a day or not.

Comment: i want to everybody (non registered)can submit a messege in the main page, by only once per day, like voting with jquery and ajax, you can vote only once, i think its by IP adress something

Comment: Yes. But like public votes, it’s also open to easy circumvention. So the only way to truly restrict posting once per day to a user, is to identify them with an account/email address. An IP, cookie etc just doesn’t cut the mustard these days.